# Python Type Hints

Tags: python, generics, types, mypy, pylance

in python 3.10 this code works, but from static code analysis I get error message from Pylance regarding "generalTypeIssue"

```py
@dataclass
class Animal():
    name:str

class Dog(Animal):
    def bark(self):
        print("whoof")
class Snake(Animal):
    def bite(self):
        print("bite!!!")

def make_animal(animal_class: type[Animal], name: str) -> Animal:
    return animal_class(name=name)

my_dog = make_animal(animal_class=Dog, name="bello")
# type(my_dog) is <class '__main__.Dog'>
my_dog.bark() <--- cannot access member bark for Animal
```

How to make a func that returns instances with correct types based on the input type?

Comment: To my knowledge you cannot make type hints dynamic so that, for example, the return type is based on the type of an argument. Possibly the best you can do is return `Union[Animal, Dog, Snake]` so the checker knows it could be any. That gets unwieldy with lots of classes, though. What you could do at the calling site is `my_dog = make_animal(Dog, "bello")  # type: Dog`. That way you explicitly tell the checker what you've created. Edit: An answer has just proven me wrong and taught me something :)

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:generics]; did you _try_ making it generic? See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i tried T = TypeVar("T", Dog, Snake) but it didn't work. The bound=Animal param was the solution

Answer (score 2):

Use a bound [`TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) to annotate the `make_animal` generic function

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TypeVar

@dataclass
class Animal:
    name: str

T = TypeVar('T', bound=Animal)

class Dog(Animal):
    def bark(self):
        print("whoof")

class Snake(Animal):
    def bite(self):
        print("bite!!!")

def make_animal(animal_class: type[T], name: str) -> T:
    return animal_class(name=name)

my_dog = make_animal(animal_class=Dog, name="bello")
# my_dog is correctly narrowed to Dog
my_dog.bark()
```